# Python CMD2 Interrupt printing promp

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am using CMD2 to create a server. I have broken my code down to the smallest bit of code that still produces the problem.

```
import socket
import _thread
from cmd2 import *

def grab_data(conn):
    while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print(data)
        except:
            print("disconnected.")
            break

def grab_client(sock):
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print("New connection")
        _thread.start_new_thread(grab_data, (conn,))


def start_conn(ip, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((ip, int(port)))
    sock.listen(10)
    print("Socket listening")
    _thread.start_new_thread(grab_client, (sock,))


class CLI(Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = "Prompt> "

    def do_listen(self, arg):
        start_conn('0.0.0.0', '4446')

    def emptyline(self):
        pass
    def do_quit(self, arg):
        return True

cli = CLI()
cli.cmdloop("Welcome to the server.")
```

The issue I run into is when a client connects. It does not reprint the prompt. It hangs at a empty line with just the cursor. I am not sure how to get the prompt to print back.

Answer (score 0):

You're blocking trying to read 1024 bytes, so it's got to wait until that entire buffer is filled. To do proper line-based buffering is a bit tricky, but a simple (albeit non-performant) implementation is to read a character at a time and check if it's a newline:

```
line = ""
while True:
   data = conn.recv(1)
   line += data
   if data in "\n\r":
       break
```

(This is not great code, but let's see if that solves the problem and we can improve it.)

Comment: That didn't help. Same issue. As soon as client connects, I get a empty cursor for prompt.